# Taking picture in Ionic2 app android

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I am developing a app where user can take his pic and save in storage firebase.

I am thinking of using Navigator.getUserMedia() of pure javascript (webcam.js) rather than native cordova camera plugin.

Is there any issue with that, like in runtime or app store submission etc?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Why don't you want to use the camera plugin for this? Is there a specific reason?

But as far as i know you would have 3 problems:

- If you want the user to edit/crop his picture before sending to Firebase you'll have to implement something with canvas.
- You'll not target users with some old versions of [Android and iOS](http://caniuse.com/#search=getusermedia). Whose is sooooo bad for your application.
- You'll lose the function of getting pictures from gallery, and having a plugin just for this is not worth since you can have a camera plugin for gallery AND camera.

If you're trying to save some lines of code it's not worth it. If you want to try something different it's OK, but not worth too. If it'll be an app and a WebApp/PWA you can just treat the platform, if is cordva you use the plugin, if it' not you'll use the `getUserMeia()`.

For the submission i can't remember if you have to point something about camera use in iOS, but it may be bad when the Apple testers try your app and it doesn't ask for camera use, it may not pass that step.

So if there's no reasonable mega good reason for using other way than the plugin, leave this idea behing.